A continuous nowhere differentiable function with $\alpha-$derivative exists at $\sup\{a\}$.
In This question I asked:

Define $g(x)= |x|$ for $|x|\in [-1,1]$ , $g(x+2)=g(x)$
$$f(x)= \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{3^n g\left(4^n x\right) }{4^n}$$ what is the $\sup \{\alpha\}$ such that
$$
\lim\limits_{h \to 0 }\frac{f(x+h)  -f(x)}{h^\alpha}= 0
$$ for all $x$?
Does the absolute value of the $\alpha-$derivative exist at that value of $\alpha$ ?

I expected that the absolute value of the $\alpha -$derivative  exist at the $\sup \{\alpha\}$ but it turns out  I was wrong  as this answers shows (the supremum is $\frac{\ln\left(\frac 4 3\right)}{\ln 4}$ btw ) .
My question is:
Is there  a continuous nowhere differentiable function  with the $\alpha-$derivative exist at that value of $\sup \{\alpha\}$ where is the sup is taken  on all reals such that $
\lim\limits_{h \to 0 }\frac{f(x+h)  -f(x)}{h^\alpha}= 0
$ for all $x$?
If it is impossible to have such function  how to prove that?

Define a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n\cdot2^n}g(4^nx)$.
We will prove that the $\alpha$-derivative $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h^\alpha}$ is $0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and for all $\alpha\leq\frac{1}{2}$, but it need not exist for $\alpha>1/2$.
First let $\alpha>1/2$; then
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{f(4^{-m})-f(0)}{(4^{-m})^\alpha}
=
\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n\cdot2^n}g(4^{n-m})}{4^{-m\alpha}}
=
\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{2^n}{n\cdot4^m}}{4^{-m\alpha}}
=
\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{2^n}{n}}{4^{-m(\alpha-1)}}
\geq
\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\frac{2^m}{m}}{4^{-m(\alpha-1)}}=\infty.
$$
Now we will take $\alpha=1/2$ and prove that the $\alpha$-derivative exists everywhere. As in my other answer, we will use the inequality $|g(x)-g(y)|\leq\min(1,|x-y|)$.
So,
$$
|g(x+h)-g(x)|=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n\cdot2^n}(g(4^n(x+h))-g(4^nx))
\leq
\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n\cdot2^n}\min(4^nh,1)
=
\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n}\min\left(2^nh,\frac{1}{2^n}\right).
$$
Let $k=k(h)=-\lfloor\log_{10}(h)\rfloor$, so that $2^k\geq h^{-\log_{10}(2)}$; continuing with the inequalities above,
$$
|g(x+h)-g(x)|\leq\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n}\min\left(2^nh,\frac{1}{2^n}\right)
\leq
\sum_{n=1}^k2^nh+\sum_{n\geq k+1}\frac{1}{k}\min\left(2^nh,\frac{1}{2^n}\right)
$$
$$\leq
2h\cdot h^{-\log_{10}(2)}+\frac{1}{k}\sum_{n\geq1}\min\left(2^nh,\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\leq2h^{1-\log_{10}(2)}+\frac{1}{k}\cdot100\sqrt{h},
$$
where the inequality $\sum_{n\geq1}\min\left(2^nh,\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\leq100\sqrt{h}$ is not hard to obtain (see my other answer for a similar inequality).
Thus,
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{\sqrt{h}}
\leq
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{2h^{1-\log_{10}(2)}+\frac{1}{k(h)}\cdot100\sqrt{h}}{\sqrt{h}}=0.
$$
